# Changing Cell Color based on Multiple Cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

I would like to know how I can set the Cell A to auto change color to red if 3 out of 4 cells (B through E) have a "Y" value.

*Screenshot provided for reference*

[image: Screenshot provided for reference]

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! What happens if you have 4 out of 4 "Y"s? What happens if 1 out 4 or 2 out 4 "Y"s?

Answer (score 0):

To do this you can create a new Conditional Formatting rule for the cells you would like to automatically change colour.

I have used the following formula:

```
=IF(SUM(IF(B2="y",1,0),IF(C2="y",1,0),IF(D2="y",1,0),IF(E2="y",1,0))>=3,TRUE,FALSE)
```

Conditional formatting rule:
[image: Conditional formatting rule]

**IF(B2="y",1,0)** - will return 1 if cell contains "Y"

**SUM(**IF(B2="y",1,0),...**)** - will sum up all returned values

**IF(**SUM(IF(B2="y",1,0),...)**>=3,TRUE,FALSE)** - checks if summed up values are greater or equal 3 and return TRUE or FALSE which is needed as an input of a Conditional Formatting rule.

This is the easiest solution I could come up with and might no be the only one correct, but I hope that helps!

Regards,
Bekson

Answer (score 0):

Select the Column A- go to **Home**- **Conditional Formatting**- **New Rule...**- **Use a formula to determine which cells to format**- enter the Formula and set the Format:

```
=COUNTIF($B1:$E1,"Y")>=3
```

[image]